# Scala Play run time injection based on request parameter

Tags: scala, dependency-injection, playframework, playframework-2.6

I am using Scala Play 2.6 and trying to use dependency injection to instantiate a service class based on request parameter. As below example code, the controller class get payment method from query string

```
package controllers

import com.google.inject.Inject
import play.api.mvc._
import scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext

class PaymentController @Inject()()
                                 (implicit ec: ExecutionContext)
  extends InjectedController  {

  def doPayment() = Action.async { implicit request =>
    request.getQueryString("payment-method").getOrElse("") match {
      case "paypal" => // Inject a PaypalPaymentService
        val paymentService = Play.current.injector.instanceOf[PaypalPaymentService]
        paymentService.processPayment()

      case "creditcard" => // Inject a CreditCardPaymentService
        val paymentService = Play.current.injector.instanceOf[CreditCardPaymentService]
        paymentService.processPayment()

      case _ => // Return error
    }
  }
}
```

And services class to process Paypal or CreditCard payment

```
package services

import scala.concurrent.Future

trait PaymentService {    
  def processPayment(): Future[Boolean]    
}

package services

import com.google.inject.Inject
import scala.concurrent.{ExecutionContext, Future}
import play.api.libs.ws.WSClient

class PaypalPaymentService @Inject()(ws: WSClient)
                                     (implicit ec: ExecutionContext)
  extends PaymentService {

  def processPayment(): Future[Boolean] = {
    //Process paypal payment
  }
}

class CreditCardPaymentService @Inject()(ws: WSClient)
                                    (implicit ec: ExecutionContext)
  extends PaymentService {

  def processPayment(): Future[Boolean] = {
    //Process credit card payment

  }
}
```

For Play 2.5 onwards, `Play.current` and `Play.application` have been deprecated.

I have two questions:

1. Is the above example code a correct way to inject a class based on
   request parameter? or is there some other better way to do so?
2. For Play 2.5/2.6, what is the way to get the application injector?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have stated correctly that `Play.current` and `Play.application` have been deprecated and from 2.5 onwards the way to use them is indeed by injecting them.

I would change your controller definition so that you make use of DI to include the needed components. Something like:

```
class PaymentController @Inject()(configuration: Configuration)
                                 (implicit ec: ExecutionContext) extends Controller  {


  // your code goes here
}
```

Now comes the tricky part. You might thing that it is possible just to inject `application: play.Application` but this is not entirely true because you are going to run into circular dependencies. This is normal because you want to inject the **whole** application while actually being in it. There is one *hack* for this and it is by injecting `Provider[Application]`. I call this a *hack* because normally you don't need/want to inject the whole application. In 99% of the cases you are interested only in specific parts - e.g. the `Configuration`, `Environment`, etc.

And here comes the solution. You can just inject your `Injector`

```
class PaymentController @Inject()(injector: Injector)
                                 (implicit ec: ExecutionContext) extends Controller  {

  // your code goes here
}
```

From here the game is an easy one. Just use the `Injector` to get the needed services. Like this:

```
case "paypal" => // Inject a PaypalPaymentService
      val paymentService = injector.instanceOf(classOf[PaypalPaymentService])
      paymentService.processPayment()
```

---

Last words regarding the "correct way" of using this. I actually find your approach OK and would not necessarily change it. Just one idea in this direction is that you create a `Module` like this:

```
import com.google.inject.AbstractModule
import com.google.inject.name.Names

class PaymentModule extends AbstractModule {
  def configure() = {

    bind(classOf[PaymentService])
      .annotatedWith(Names.named("paypal"))
      .to(classOf[PaypalPaymentService])

    bind(classOf[PaymentService])
      .annotatedWith(Names.named("creditcard"))
      .to(classOf[CreditCardPaymentService])
  }
}
```

Having a common trait (as you do it) helps in this case and you can have multiple implementations, even mocked ones for your tests. The module will be registered automatically if it lies in the root package. Otherwise you should tell Play the location of it:

`play.modules.enabled += "modules.PaymentModule"`

Comment: Great answer! Injecting an injector seems the right way to go.